# how to initiate a generic variable to zero in haxe

Tags: haxe, generic-programming

I am trying to write an general function in Haxe3.01 for summing an array of numbers, as follows:

```
static public function sum<T:(Int,Float)>(xs:Array<T>):T {
    var z:T = 0;  //! not OK        
    for (i in 0...xs.length)
        z = z + xs[i];      
    return z;
}
```

The above won't compile and haxe says that `... : Int should be sum.T`, even though 0 is defined for both Int and Float in the type constraint for T. Then I tried to work around the problem by trying to get a zero for the type T. One version was:

```
@:generic static public function zero<T:(Int,Float)>):T {
    var x:T; //! not OK
    return x - x;
}
```

This one won't compile because `x` in `zero()` isn't initialized. To initialize it, I need to some how specify in the type constraint of T that it has a new operator. Maybe, I can use

```
@:generic static public function zero<T:{function new():Void;}>():T {
    var x:T = new T();
    return x - x; //! not OK
}
```

, following http://haxe.org/manual/haxe3/features. But then, `-` operator is not defined. Unless there is a way to initialize a local variable of type `<T:(Int,Float)>`, I don't see how this would work.

This is probably already too much work just to get a zero. My questions is, of course, how to make this work for such a function with typed parameters.

Thanks.

-- Update --

After some reading, I learned that `cast` could be used:

```
static public function sum<T:(Int,Float)>(xs:Array<T>):T {
    var z:T = cast(0);
    for (i in 0...xs.length)
        z = z + xs[i];      
    return z;   }
```

This feels like a hack though. Also, it wouldn't work,e.g. if sum is to work on a potential "Pair" type, which defines `-` and has (0,0) as the zero element.

Answer (score 0):

Ints can be converted to floats implicitly.  You can remove the Int constraint, and just use the Float.

See also : [haxe "should be int" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518458/haxe-should-be-int-error)