# haxe "should be int" error

Tags: haxe, type-parameter

Haxe seems to assume that certain things must be `Int`. In the following function,

```
class Main {
    static function main() {
        function mult_s<T,A>(s:T,x:A):A { return cast s*x; }
        var bb = mult_s(1.1,2.2);
    }
}
```

I got (with Haxe 3.01):

```
Main.hx:xx: characters 48-49 : mult_s.T should be Int
Main.hx:xx: characters 50-51 : mult_s.A should be Int
```

Can anyone please explain why `T` and `A` should be `Int` instead of `Float`?

---

A more puzzling example is this:

```
class Main {
    public static function min<T:(Int,Float)>(t:T, t2:T):T { return t < t2 ? t : t2; }
    static function main() {
        var a = min(1.1,2.2); //compile error
        var b = min(1,2); //ok
    }
}
```

I can't see why `t<t2` implies that either `t` or `t2` is Int. But Haxe seems prefer `Int`: `min` is fine if called with `Int`'s but fails if called with `Float`'s. Is this reasonable?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`min<T:(Int,Float)>` means `T` should be **both** `Int` **and** `Float`. See the [constraints section of Haxe Manual](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/HaxeManual/blob/master/md/manual/type-system-type-parameter-constraints.md).

Given `Int` can be converted to `Float` implicitly, you can safely remove the constraint of `Int`. i.e. the following will works:

http://try.haxe.org/#420bC

```
class Test {
  public static function min<T:Float>(t:T, t2:T):T { return t < t2 ? t : t2; }
  static function main() {
    var a = min(1.1,2.2); //ok
    $type(a); //Float
    trace(a); //1.1
    var b = min(1,2); //ok
    $type(b); //Int
    trace(b); //1
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "min<T:(Int,Float)> means T should be both Int and Float", is there a reference for this?

Comment: Also, the second line `var b = min(1,2); `, I expected `b` to be an `Int`. But it is really a `Float` in your case, isn't it?

Comment: I've just updated the answer. The return type of `min` is `T`, which is also the type of the function arguments `t` and `t2`. So when you put `Int` inside, it will return `Int`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The reference does suggest that constraints `<T:(Measurable,Iterable>)` to be both measurable and iterable. It's still wierd to think how can something be both `Int` and `Float`. What if it is about `<T:(String,Float)>`, pretending that we can compare Strings.

Comment: BTW, the code in your example gives a compile error message:  `Test.hx:4: characters 18-21 : Float should be Int
Test.hx:4: characters 18-21 : For function argument 't2'`   about the line `var a = min(1.1,2.2);`

Comment: Arhh, there was a typo in the try-haxe code, `1` should be `1.1`. I've updated the code and the link.

Comment: Sadly there is no syntax for **or** constraints at the moment. Solving this problem require usage of abstract type: http://try.haxe.org/#17b58